# Usage of web services with session-state cookieless=true

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session-state, webmethod, cookieless

Enable sessions in a web service method like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Use a cookieless session state (web.config):

```
<sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>
```

Then try to call it from a client like this:

```
localhost.WebService1 ws1 = new localhost.WebService1();    // the web service proxy        
ws1.HelloWorld();
```

You get a redirect WebException (302) saying that the object has been moved:

[image]

Comment: What's the base class for localhost.WebService1 ?

Comment: SoapHttpClientProtocol (namespace ´System.Web.Services.Protocols´), as it has been generated automatically by .NET.

Comment: You have the Boolean property "AllowAutoRedirect" there, please check if it's false by default, change it to true, and test it

Comment: Please see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Microsoft article describes this issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx

The call from the client has to catch the WebException, and update the URL to the webservice, which has to include the sessionId generated by the web server. Then repeat the call to the method:

```
localhost.WebService1 ws1 = new localhost.WebService1();    // the web service proxy    
try {
    ws1.HelloWorld();
} catch (WebException ex) {
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found) {
        ws1.Url = new Uri(new Uri(ws1.Url), response.Headers["Location"]).AbsoluteUri;
        ws1.HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation of SoapHttpClientProtocol, the property "AllowAutoRedirect" has a default value of false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Changing it to true before calling the web method will automatically handle a 302 http redirect response.

Comment: This does not work, and gives an error (as also steted in the Microsoft article I linked to in my answer): Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 
    but expected 'text/xml'